# Unable to call Lock Screen view controller from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, locking, lockscreen, appdelegate

I have implemented the `KKLockscreen` view controller and is working well within the in-app settings controller. Able to set passcode and change them as well.

I am having problem to call he lock screen view from appdelegate. I have added delegate .h file and imported the view controller in .m file. still it's not calling the lockscreen. any help?

below is my code.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([[KKPasscodeLock sharedLock] isPasscodeRequired]) {
        KKPasscodeViewController *vc = [[KKPasscodeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        vc.mode = KKPasscodeModeEnter;
        vc.delegate = self;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
            UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
                nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
                nav.navigationBar.opaque = NO;
            } else {
                nav.navigationBar.tintColor = _navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
                nav.navigationBar.translucent = _navigationController.navigationBar.translucent;
                nav.navigationBar.opaque = _navigationController.navigationBar.opaque;
                nav.navigationBar.barStyle = _navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle;
            }

            [_navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:NO];
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have checked it with my code and it is working ,ya but you have not  give nib name here in this line and i have given may be that why it is not displaying your view.
 KKPasscodeViewController *vc = [[KKPasscodeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
RootViewController *vc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        nav.navigationBar.opaque = NO;
    } else {
        nav.navigationBar.tintColor = navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
        nav.navigationBar.translucent = navigationController.navigationBar.translucent;
        nav.navigationBar.opaque = navigationController.navigationBar.opaque;
        nav.navigationBar.barStyle = navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle;
    }

    [navigationController presentModalViewController:nav animated:NO];
});
```

}

Comment: Shall i use as follows?


        KKPasscodeViewController *vc = [[KKPasscodeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KKPasscodeViewController" bundle:nil];


but it doesn't work. sorry. i am not so clear which nib name to use.

Comment: I have two question                                                 1>your view controller is not showing in ipad version or iphone version?                                                                                                                                           2>if ([[KKPasscodeLock sharedLock] isPasscodeRequired]) return true ? and control goes in the code or not?

Comment: 1. In both iPhone and iPad version doesn't show. 
2. the original KKLockscreen comes with a demo app and its working well. I beleive the control shall goes to the code when ([[KKPasscodeLock sharedLock] isPasscodeRequired]) return true.

I am actually incorporating the codes from demo app into my app. settings panels works great. just that it is not being called from appdelegate. i am using storyboard. but the KKPasscodeViewController is made up with codes. not implemented in storyboard. is it might be the problem?